# SPWebPartManager.SaveChanges throws an error

Tags: web-part, powershell

I a getting the following exception when I try to update the view of a web part.

```
Exception calling "SaveChanges" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

This is the code:

```
$web = get-spweb $webUrl
$wpPage = $web.GetFile("SitePages/home.aspx")
$tasksList = $web.Lists["Tasks"]

$v = $tasksList.Views["Calendar"]
    $WpManager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($wpPage,[System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);
    foreach($webpart in $WpManager.WebParts)
    {


        if($list.BaseTemplate -eq "TasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy" -and $webpart.Title -eq "Tasks")
        {
            $webpart.ViewGuid = $v.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper()
            $webpart.ViewId = $v.BaseViewID
            $WpManager.SaveChanges($webpart);  
        }
    }
```

What should I instantiate to make Savechange work? It does not throw this error in my dev machine. What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the property named ListName for $wp before call SaveChanges

```
$wp.ListName = $tasksList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
```